# VHDL: Signal vs Port

Tags: fpga, vhdl, port

Synchronization:

```
---------------------
Port ( ...
                  rotary_a : in std_logic;
                  rotary_b : in std_logic;
...);
...
signal      rotary_a_in : std_logic;
signal      rotary_b_in : std_logic;
signal      rotary_in : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
...
      rotary_a_in <= rotary_a;
      rotary_b_in <= rotary_b;
...
      rotary_in <= rotary_b_in & rotary_a_in;
---------------------
```

in the last step, what is the advantage of using temporary signals?
one could achieve same output using ports directly (`rotary_b & rotary_a`)

Comment: Check out http://www.sigasi.com/content/vhdls-crown-jewel, it talks about delta cycles and compares vhdl with verilog in that respect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this example, none and yes.

There will be one difference : the rotary_in signal will be generated one delta cycle earlier if you make the obvious change.

If there is something else dodgy in the rest of the design; for example, assignments on a clock signal (delaying it by an unnecessary delta cycle) the two versions may show different results in simulation.

It would be better to fix the real problem; e.g. clock signal but if you are using IP over which you have no control you may occasionally need to resort to bodges like this. Then it is better to say

```
rotary_a_in <= rotary_a after 1 ps;
```

and comment why...